# can limit of a function be a measure?

Tags: limits, weak-convergence, pointwise-convergence

What is the limit when $\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+$ of
$$
x\mapsto \sin(x/\epsilon)
$$
?

It doesn't seem to be a function. Is it a measure ?

Comment: As a distribution it converges to $0$ because the rapid oscillations will make adjacent half-periods cancel out.